# Unable to generate ListView on my Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I almost tried for an hour and figuring out why my listView is not getting displayed on the fragment.I am a beginner in Android and this should be really easy for the experts.I really tried my best to figure out ,but still i am unable to generate the listView.

The app is very simple which has oneFragment and i am trying to add ListView ,which is showing blank data always.I am trying to push some list of strings via adapter class.It looks like onCreateView on fragment_main.java is not been called and i am not sure why.I have uploaded the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/karthik-krishnaswamy17/SunShineApp_Scratch/tree/SunshinenotWorking)

It would be great if someone helps me on this.
Thanks

Comment: Please don't just link to your project off-site. You need to include a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: +1 for Mark's comments. Still I looked at your project, this is not how you include a fragment inside an Activity. Start with how to attach a fragment to Activity and the play with ListView. Polish your basics first before jumping on advance stuff.

Comment: To have best practice in your programming, the first character of your fragment_main class should be capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

you forget to attach the fragment to MainActivity

```
     FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragment_main frag= new fragment_main();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, frag, "HELLO");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

put this code in MainActivity

Also add the id `fragment_container` to your activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    >


    <include
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        layout="@layout/fragment_main"/>
</LinearLayout>
```